# About calculating limits of integrals (Part 2)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, computer-algebra-systems

The function $tanh(\pi z)$ has its poles at the points $i(n+\frac{1}{2})$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now I want to take an $\epsilon$ circle around such a pole and contour integrate the function $z\text{ }tanh(\pi z) log(z^2 + a^2)$ around it in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ (and $a >0$)

Basicaly I want to compute $lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} [ \int _{\phi = -\pi} ^{\pi} z\text{ }tanh(\pi z) log(z^2 + a^2) dz]$ for $z = i(n+\frac{1}{2}) + \epsilon e^{i\phi}$

- Is this a meaningful calculation?
- I tried computing this quantity on Wolfram alpha but I couldn't get any answer,

> Series [ (I*x + y*exp(I*p))*(tanh (pi*(I*x + y*exp(I*p))) )*(log ((
>   I*x +  y*exp(I*p) )^2 + a^2))*(I*y*exp(I*p)), {y,0,2}, {Assuming
>   x>0,y>0,a>0, p real}]

- If I understand Mathematica correctly it is evaluating,

$$lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} [ \int _{\phi = -\pi} ^{\pi} z\text{ }tanh(\pi z) log(z^2 + a^2) dz] \text{ for }z = i(n+\frac{1}{2}) + \epsilon e^{i\phi} = (1+2n)log[a^2 - (n +\frac{1}{2})^2]$$

Am I using Mathematica correctly?

Comment: What branch of the $\log$ is that?

Comment: Imagine that the branchcut of the function $log(z^2 + a^2)$ is taken to start at $\pm ia$ and goes up/down the $y-$axis. Also you can assume that the point $i(n+\frac{1}{2})$ is between the points $\pm ia$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at $i/2.$ I assume $a>1/2$ and that $\log z$ is the principal branch. Then $\log (a^2+z^2)$ is analytic in a deleted neighborhood of $i/2.$ By the residue theorem, for small $\epsilon$ your integral is $2\pi i$ times the residue of the integrand at $i/2.$ Finding the residue is not too bad because $\cosh z$ has a zero of order $1$ at $i/2.$ The residue equals
$$\lim_{z\to i/2} \frac{(z-i/2)z\sinh \pi z \log (a^2+z^2)}{\cosh \pi z}.$$
Now $(z-i/2)/\cosh \pi z \to 1/[\pi \sinh (\pi i/2)].$ Thus the above limit is $(i/2)\log (a^2-1/4))/\pi.$ Multiply that by $2\pi i$ to get $-\pi \log (a^2 - 1/4).$ My answer is different from the one you posted.

Comment: Could you kindly explain as to what you mean by saying that ``$log z$ is the principal branch"? (Does it mean the same as my way of specifying where I am choosing to put my branch-cuts?)

Comment: I am not vouching for my Mathematica answer. I don't trust my Mathematica skills :D I would be delighted if someone could check what is the answer on Mathematica!

Comment: Can you explain how you took this limit to show that $\frac{z - i/2}{cosh (\pi z ) } \rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi sinh (\pi i/2) }$ ?

Comment: Your answer doesn't look right :  The answer to the integral is $2\pi i (Res_{z = i/2} [z\tanh (\pi z) \log(z^2+a^2) ] )$ The only one having a pole is the $tanh$ part and $Res_{z = i/2} [ tanh (\pi z) ] = 1/\pi$. So the answer to the integral is $(2\pi i )*(i/2)*(1/\pi)*\log (a^2 - 1/4 ) = - log(a^2 - 1/4)$